# Open URL with all the scripts by browser's js in background

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to open URL by browser's js and make browser load all the scripts and execute them, but invisible to user? Like Selenium inside browser. xmlhttprequest isn't enough - it just gets server response without executing js. I need this because target page is composed by js and I can't use xmlhttprequest because it returns no data.

Some pseudocode to illustrate:

```
// Load URL and execute all the js that adds data to the page
new_doc = new Document('http://...');
new_doc.querySelector('...');
```

Comment: you can use web workers

Comment: @ricky, how? afaik web workers is to run calculations outside main thread. How it could load whole page with js?